# Angular server side pagination with dynamic table component

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote the following code to create a dynamic table component to load data in it, with this component I'm now trying to achieve server side pagination:

**table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableDataSrc: any;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-input-rename
  @Input('tableColumns') tableCols: string[];
  @Input() tableData: {}[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  //   this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
  //   this.tableDataSrc.sort = this.sort;
  //   this.tableDataSrc.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.tableData.currentValue) {
        this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
        this.tableDataSrc.sort = this.sort;
        this.tableDataSrc.paginator = this.paginator;
    }
}

}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">


<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSrc" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableCols">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ col }}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{ col | titlecase }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let profile">{{ profile[col] }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableCols"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableCols"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**team.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Team } from "../models/team";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TeamService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getTeams(page:number=1){
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8000/api/teams', {
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set("page", page.toString())
    }
    )
  }
}
```

**teams.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TeamService } from 'src/app/services/team.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teams',
  templateUrl: './teams.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teams.component.scss']
})
export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {
  public teams : any; 

  tableCols = ['sofascore_id', 'name'];

  constructor(private teamService : TeamService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.teamService.getTeams().pipe(first()).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.teams = data.results
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.error)
      }
    ) 
  }

}
```

**teams.component.html**

```html
<app-table [tableData]="teams" [tableColumns]="tableCols"></app-table>
```

My question: How am I going to achieve server side pagination? I know that the page parameter in the `getTeams` function is missing, but how do I pass this from the paginator to that. I looked at multiple tutorials and examples (like https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Output() page: EventEmitter<PageEvent>` event from [MatPaginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator) and delegate that event up to the `TeamsComponent` and use it to trigger service request. See [here for PageEvent](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#PageEvent).

Add following to **table.component.ts** before constructor;

```js
@Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<PageEvent>();
```

in **table.component.html**;

```html
<mat-paginator (page)="pageChange.emit($event)"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20]" 
               showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>
```

in **teams.component.html**;

```html
<app-table (pageChange)="handlePageChange($event)" [tableData]="teams" [tableColumns]="tableCols"></app-table>
```

in **teams.componet.ts**;

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchTeams(); 
  }

  fetchTeams(pageNumber = 1){
    this.teamService.getTeams(pageNumber).pipe(first()).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.teams = data.results
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.error)
      }
    )
  }

  handlePageChange(event: PageEvent) {
    this.fetchTeams(event.pageIndex)
  }
```

Apart from your question, you need to change `getTeams` api in a way that it takes also page size into account. Otherwise your service response will always give same number of items per page, no matter what page size user selects from `MatPaginator`. Alternatively you can set a fixed page size (same size as server response) on `MatPaginator`, i.e. set `[pageSizeOptions]="[15]"` on `mat-paginator` assuming that your server response always returns 15 items.

Comment: But how does the paginator know the total number of items? My server side only returns 15 items at the time

Comment: Good point :) you should get total number of items from server when `TeamsComponent` first loads then pass it down to `TableComponent` and assign it to the `length` property of `mat-paginator`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the pageChange funciton is not passed correctly since I get the error that it does not exists using your code

Comment: Did you add `@Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<PageEvent>();` to `TeamsComponent`? What is the exact error.Can you post it here?

Comment: Yes I did and this the error `Property 'pageChange' does not exist on type 'TableComponent'.`

Comment: Is it possible that you typed `[pageChange]="handlePageChange($event)"` instead of `(pageChange)="handlePageChange($event)"` ? It should be parenthesis around `pageChange` not square brackets.

Comment: I have the brackets on it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `@Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<PageEvent>();` should go into `TableComponent` not `TeamsComponent`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214124/discussion-between-sander-bakker-and-ysf).